# What is the most efficient way to automatically cleanse this data on Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to StackOverflow and I am looking for someone who could help me with this. I have thoroughly searched the website and I could not find an answer to my question.

I am looking for an automated way (VBA possibly) to cleanse the data below. My problem is that the text I want to get rid of is irregular in content and length so I cannot apply the regular formulas and I will need a complex formula that will enable me to get some clean data.

Here is an extract of the data I am coming across:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONObL.png]

As you can see above there are two columns and in the second one I would like to get rid of the information on the right hand side, after the big space.

Is there a formula to enable me to delete this type of text?

Comment: Honestly you'd be best to just try sourcing the data in a better structure, there is clearly no set rule or logic to apply that would work against all of that data.

Comment: Some of these have 2 large spaces, is it just the first column you want in those cases or the first and second column and omit the third? The 6th line of data also isn't clear if you want the CB removed or something else

Comment: @Zerk Its true the data could be formatted alot better however based on the OPs question they want anything after more than a single space removed, which VBA (And most, if not all, programming languages) can do with ease

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the prompt response.

This is the raw data as I exported it. I would be looking to keep the first part on the left in the second column, and get rid of the second part after the double space.

I am not sure If I want the CB removed. I don't really care much for that one specifically.

Ideally yea, anything that could remove everything that is after a double space ;)

Comment: @Mr.Burns it's clear that columns 2 & 3 are combined into one. There's no clear behavior for separating out the two, some rows have spaces of different lengths, some of column 2's data is split by spaces. delimiting by spaces will work for some rows and for others will cut the second column in half.

Comment: @Zerk There isn't a third column. As I have pulled the data it came out like this. It is tricky because the spaces are irregular.

Considering the wording of the "3rd column" varies based on the content of the first column, would it be possible to create a formula that says "IF column 1 says "PAYMENT", DELETE everything after "ON" ?

Comment: @TheMedster Check my answer, it removes anything after a double space, but if I was you I would try to also improve how you get that data, if its from an automated source then its easier but, however that data is created needs to be cleaned up

Comment: @Mr.Burns Thanks for your help! It isn't automated. I am pulling this from my bank account and I have to log in and download the spreadsheet. I am sceptical my bank would give me access to this data in an automated way...

Unless you have any recommendations?

Comment: @TheMedster If its your bank then nothing you can do, I have updated my answer with a formula method as well

Comment: @Mr.Burns Cool. I am looking to have it in  Macro to automate it so that everytime I paste my raw data and run the macro it cleanses it. Do you know how to run the macro until the last row without having to specify it? (It varies depending on the number of transactions I made in the month)

Comment: @TheMedster `lastrow = activesheet.cells(activesheet.rows.count,3).end(xlup).row` is the easiest way for me, look on Google "VBA Get last row" should get a decent amount of results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until I have an answer to my question in comment I shall give this answer

```
For RowCount = FirstRow to Lastrow
Activesheet.Cells(RowCount, 3).Value = Split(Activesheet.Cells(RowCount, 3).Value, "  ")(0)
Next RowCount
```

The way this works is it takes the value of the cell and `Split()` will use the delimiter "  ", Double space, and replace the first value into the cell

You will need to specify the first & last row of which there are many examples of how to do online

`=LEFT( A1, FIND( "  ", A1 ) - 1 )`

This is a formula of what you want as well it finds a double spacing and takes what is to the left of of the double spacing, the -1 removes the space left over at the end of the returned value